# Installing mongrel service on Windows 2008

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, mongrel, installanywhere

We use InstallAnywhere to install our product.  One of the components that it needs to install is mongrel.  IA invokes the following command line during installation:

```
mongrel_rails service::install -N service-1 -D "Service 1" -c "C:\app_dir\\rails\rails_apps\service-1" -p 19000 -e production
```

Apprently under the hoods "sc create..." is used.

The installation works great on Windows 2003.  On Windows 2008 though this operation requires elevated privileges.

When I login as local administrator (ie 'local-machine\administrator' user), the installation works just fine.  However, when I login as a domain user that is part of local administrators group, the services fails to install with error "access is denied".

How can I make it possible to install the product without having to login as local administrator?

Thanks!

Couple of notes I would like to add.  One solution I tried is to execute the installer as administrator.  The service does get installed.  However, it creates another problem.  An embedded 3rd party product and its files get installed with admin only rights.  So we do need to run the installer as logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the installer's manifest to require administrator privileges in order to run? That should cause a UAC prompt to elevate privileges, but it should still run as the logged in user. There is a setting in InstallShield to control this, but I'm not sure about InstallAnywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried dumbing down the UAC setting for the account in use? http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm may be a resource.

Comment: In general, requiring that UAC be disabled for users to install/run software should be avoided because disabling UAC could be a security risk. Instead, software should be designed to be able to run with least privileges. In some situations, it might not even be possible to disable UAC (e.g. security policy set at the domain level).